# Creating a search add-on for collecting data

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, search, add-on

I wanted to create a search add-on to right click and search tag text into Wikipedia/
but when i apply this code it only shows the option in context menu but nothing happens//

i don't know where the error is....

i was planning on right clicking it and making it search different words from the same page [thispage](http://phrontistery.info/a.html) and get results in a new tab... //

My code:

exports.main = function() {

```
var contextMenu = require("context-menu");
var tabs = require("tabs");
var Request = require('request');

var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
    label: "Start Search",
    context: contextMenu.PageContext(),
    contentScript: 'self.on("click", function() {'+
                        'var text = window.getElementsByTagName(\"td\").toString();'+
                        'self.postMessage(text);'+
                        '});',
    onMessage: function(text) {
                    tabs.open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search="+text)
                }
    }) ;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following error in your script,

```
'var elements=document.getElementsByTagName('td'); " +
```

should be

```
'var elements=document.getElementsByTagName(\'td\'); " +
```

Comment: thanks/ do you know where to enter the setInterval() so that i can make it loop

Answer (score 0):

test this:

```
exports.main = function() {

    var contextMenu = require("context-menu");
    var tabs = require("tabs");     

    var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
        label: "Start Search",
        context: contextMenu.PageContext(),
        contentScript: 'self.on("click", function() {'+
        'var elements=document.getElementsByTagName("td");' +
                "for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++) { " +
                "self.postMessage(elements);"+
                            "});",
        onMessage: function(elements) {
                        tabs.open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search"+elements);
                    }                        
        }) ;

    };
```

Comment: thanks/ do you know where to enter the setInterval() so that i can make it loop.or something like setTimeout()